# Odoo installed on AWS not printing on local printer

Tags: amazon-web-services, printing, odoo, local

I installed community edition of Odoo on Amazon ubuntu. All features are working but cant able to print on local printer. I also install odoo Community edition on my local ubuntu machine and its working fine on local printer. I am not getting how to print from aws to my local printer.

Comment: Abhijeet, Can you please add more details like which printer you are talking about normal printer or POS printer? And if yes then also please add more details about POS printers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to install CUPS server on your local machine where the printer is connected .

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own instance, install a local printer server with cups, connect this with VPN (wireguard or openvpn) to your instance, and configure your local cups server as a remote printer on odoo.
You only need cups client on the odoo side.
The VPN can be 100% point-to-point (so use wireguard). No need for routing or firewalls.